# Capture response from specific URL using FiddlerCore

Tags: c#, winforms, fiddlercore

I am working on an Application that captures responses using FiddlerCore.
Since I am new to FiddlerCore and I couldn't find any help online I decided to ask the question my self.

Here is the concept I have: The user will navigate to a website (let's say https://pastebin.com) on their web browser or via something else. The application will capture the content that pastebin.com responded back (even if its the source/HTML code.)

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jul/29/using-fiddlercore-to-capture-http-requests-with-net

Comment: As I said, I'm new to FiddlerCore. It would be nice if you can send me something more simple.